Usage of carets inside a button
In our UI, we have “More” buttons that, when clicked, open a menu with additional related options compared to other buttons in the button toolbar. These buttons have a caret next to the label, signifying to users that there are more options available in the menu.
However, in the same button toolbar, we can also have a “New” button with two options: “Create new X” and “Create new Y.” I believe the decision to use a caret depends on what happens when the button is clicked.
If clicking the “New” button opens a menu with these two options, there should be a caret next to the label.
On the other hand, if clicking the “New” button opens a new dialog where users can choose between “Create new X” and “Create new Y,” a caret may not be necessary.In this case how do I let users know there are more options?
Edit: I would like to additionally expand this question. For now I want to focus on buttons that have a sub-menu. After checking other design systems I came to the following conclusion. Classic buttons (Container + Label) always have a caret to indicate a sub-menu. But the "tricky" part is when it comes to major use case buttons and buttons that are icon only.
Major use case buttons: In our team we find it weird that a major use case button in a button toolbar would have a caret. I know that if we want to follow best usability practice we should also have a caret there but like I said to us it feels weird.
Icon only buttons: A lot of design systems does not predict using carets with icon only buttons (Microsoft uses it in office tools, but that is another story). This makes sense to me with "More" icon since it's universally recognized and users understand its behavior.
But in our UI's we have "New" button as an icon only (+) or a classic button (border and label). So if we don't use a caret with "Icon Only Button" but we use it with the "Classic" button we are inconsistent. User testing is unfortunately not possible.
Does anyone have any recommendations or experience with similar issues?
Thank you.

Would be nice to include an illustration of how doe your buttons with a caret look.

We've used ellipsis to indicate that a button doesn't immediately execute a function, but opens a dialogue first...

This is the proper way to do it

Thank you for your answer. So it should be something like this "New..."

A caret can be a good indicator in both versions that they user will see a popover with more options. Showing the popover on hover/click can efficient and provide a consistent visual cue that there are multiple actions from that action.
I think the caret is a great option, you can test if the actions are shown on hover/click, and test options from there. A more menu can be great if it has multiple secondary actions, but I'm assuming the add action is primary to the other menus in this case.
